# How to make this complex select statement with WHERE condition looking into another table and with joined fields from third table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables as following:

**Lessons**

| id | title | public | course_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | title1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | title2 | 0 | 11 |

**Enrolments**

| id | user_id | course_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 11 |

**LessonProgress**

| id | user_id | lesson_id | completed_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 2 | Some date |
| 2 | 101 | 1 | Some date |

Given a *lesson_id* and *user_id*.
I need to fetch a lesson by given *lesson_id* and the query should return result only if the lesson has *public* set to **TRUE (1)** OR there is an entry in **Enrolments** table with the given *user_id* and a *course_id* that this particular lesson belongs.
Also, the result should have a boolean field, say named "completed" that is true if there is an entry in the **LessonProgress** table for the given *lesson_id* and the *user_id*

So if given user_id: 100 and lesson_id: 1, the query should return:

| id | title | public | course_id | completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | title1 | 1 | 10 | false |

And for a given user_id: 100 and lesson_id: 2, the query should return:

| id | title | public | course_id | completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | title2 | 0 | 11 | true |

And for the user_id: 101 and the lesson_id: 2 the query should return no results.

Hope this all make sense.

I am trying to wrap my head around how to do it but not very skilled at SQL craft.

If someone can also suggest a good online read on SQL witchery like this, I'd appreciate but the main question is how do I write a query that do what I need.

** **UPDATE** **

Here is the query that I came up with that covers the functional requirements.

```
vars $LESSON_ID, $USER_ID

select lesson.*, progress.completed_at from Lessons as lesson
left join (select LessonProgress.* from LessonProgress where LessonProgress.user_id=$USER_ID) as progress on lesson.id = progress.lesson_id
where lesson.id = $LESSON_ID
AND (
  lesson.public = 1
  OR (
    EXISTS 
      (SELECT enrolment.user_id, enrolment.course_id FROM Enrolments as enrolment WHERE enrolment.user_id = $USER_ID AND enrolment.course_id = lesson.course_id)
  )
)
```

[here is the fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=06feb716f963aeadaca01035cb955ade)

But I do not know if this is optimal performance wise. There is one `EXISTS` and one extra `select` for the progress table which I then left-join.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Show us the query you have tried so far? *if the lesson has preview set* makes no sense with your test data.

Comment: Apologies, the "preview" meant to me "public". My bad, I updated the question.

Comment: Little confused on the data sample provided. In the first case for user_id = 100 and lesson_id = 1, how the user 100 and lesson 1 is related. 100 is enrolled to course 11 and course 11 hase only one lesson id 2.  Could you please explain?

Comment: @praveen because the lesson 1 has the "public" true, which means that any user should be able to query it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

**BIG FAT NOTE**

*I realised that the question slowly morphed form "how do I do this?" to more of a "Is there a better way to do it?"*

*For the sake of completeness I am going to post this as an answer and if there are better options suggested later I will take it as accepted answer, if nothing in a week, I will accept my own.*

---

My last update in the question contains a query that does the job I needed but I was not sure if it is optimal.

There are two things that concerned me:

- subquery for the *join*
- extra *select* for the *EXISTS*

I did some extra digging and removed the first concern. Did not realise that the `ON` in the *join* can have `AND`.
So, instead of doing a subquery and joining it, I directly left-join the LessonProgress table.

Looking at the use of `EXISTS` versus `JOIN` I stumbled one comment pointing that the `EXISTS` will stop as soon as the match is found while `JOIN` will execute for the entire table. And the advice was, generally, to use `JOIN` if I need to return the data and `EXISTS` if I don't. Hence, it looks like `EXISTS` is better candidate here.

My final query:

```
var $USER_ID $LESSON_ID

select lesson.*, progress.completed_at from Lessons as lesson
left join LessonProgress as progress on lesson.id = progress.lesson_id and progress.user_id=$USER_ID
where lesson.id = $LESSON_ID
AND (
  lesson.public = 1
  OR (
    EXISTS 
      (SELECT enrolment.user_id, enrolment.course_id FROM Enrolments as enrolment WHERE enrolment.user_id = $USER_ID AND enrolment.course_id = lesson.course_id)
  )
)
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0d0f2e0e37d203b9dd7d62f60319fd8f)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain about the sample data particularly for "completed" because in both cases I see "Some date", but I believe the queries are:

> ```
> select
> *
> from Lessons l
> left join Enrolments e on l.course_id = e.course_id
> inner join LessonProgress p on l.id = p.lesson_id
> ```
>
> ```
> id | title  | public | course_id | id   | user_id | course_id | id | user_id | lesson_id | completed_at
> -: | :----- | :----- | --------: | :--- | ------: | --------: | -: | ------: | --------: | :-----------
>  2 | title2 | false. |        11 | 1    |     100 |        11 |  1 |     100 |         2 | Some date   
>  1 | title1 | true   |        10 | null |    null |      null |  2 |     101 |         1 | Some date
> ```

> ```
> select
> *
> from Lessons l
> left join Enrolments e on l.course_id = e.course_id
> inner join LessonProgress p on l.id = p.lesson_id
> where (e.user_id = 100 or p.user_id = 100)
> and (lesson_id = 1 or l.public = false)
> ```
>
> ```
> id | title  | public | course_id | id | user_id | course_id | id | user_id | lesson_id | completed_at
> -: | :----- | :----- | --------: | :- | ------: | --------: | -: | ------: | --------: | :-----------
>  2 | title2 | false. |        11 | 1  |     100 |        11 |  1 |     100 |         2 | Some date
> ```

> ```
> select
> *
> from Lessons l
> left join Enrolments e on l.course_id = e.course_id
> inner join LessonProgress p on l.id = p.lesson_id
> where (e.user_id = 100 or p.user_id = 100)
> and (lesson_id = 2 or l.public = false)
> ```
>
> ```
> id | title  | public | course_id | id | user_id | course_id | id | user_id | lesson_id | completed_at
> -: | :----- | :----- | --------: | :- | ------: | --------: | -: | ------: | --------: | :-----------
>  2 | title2 | false. |        11 | 1  |     100 |        11 |  1 |     100 |         2 | Some date
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=964683af14bf10b4e1d0bc99b1ee93e6&hide=1)*

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't do what I need. I have updated my question with the query that I came up with that does exactly what I need but I wonder if it is performant and whether it can be optimised.